# How can this come up from ¬∃x¬(Atom(x)∨EmptySpace(x)) to ∀x(Atom(x)∨EmptySpace(x))?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

When I tried to answer this question

> Atomism, the statement that everything is made up of tiny, indivisible, unchangeable particles, which are called “atoms”, was originally proposed by two Greek philosophers -- Democritus (460-371B.C.) and Leucippus (early 5th century B.C.). Its central argument, nothing exists except atoms and empty space, can be paraphrased as there exists no such thing that is neither an atom nor empty space and written as  **¬∃x(¬Atom(x)∧¬EmptySpace(x))**  in FOL.
>
> This FOL sentence, however, is somewhat cumbersome, and can be simplified using de Morgan's laws. Which of the following is equivalent to the sentence, and cannot be simplified further?

my answer was wrong. So, I checked the key answer and here is the correct:

> This is a neat version of Atomism's original statement, which is achieved by first applying de Morgan's law to  ¬Atom(x)∧¬EmptySpace(x)  inside the parenthesis and get  ¬(Atom(x)∨EmptySpace(x)) , then applying de Morgan's law for quantifiers on  **¬∃x¬(Atom(x)∨EmptySpace(x))**  and get  **∀x(Atom(x)∨EmptySpace(x))** , which says that everything (that exists) is either an atom or empty space.

In the correct answer, how can this come up from **¬∃x¬(Atom(x)∨EmptySpace(x))** to **∀x(Atom(x)∨EmptySpace(x))** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make things clearer, let us use $A$ and $E$ rather than $\text{Atom}$ and $\text{EmptySpace}$.

We start with: "There is no thing that is both not $A$ and not $E$". $$\lnot\exists x~(\lnot A(x)\land\lnot E(x))$$

Invoking deMorgan's Laws: "There is no thing that is not either $A$ or $E$." $$\lnot\exists x~\lnot(A(x)\lor E(x))$$

Invoking quantifier duality: "Every thing is either $A$ or $E$." $$\forall x~(A(x)\lor E(x))$$

That is all.

---

De Morgan's laws are that ${(\lnot p\land\lnot q)\iff\lnot(p\lor q)\\(\lnot p\lor\lnot q)\iff\lnot(p\land q)\\\text{et cetera}}$

Quantifier duality is that ${\lnot\exists x~\phi\iff\forall x~\lnot\phi\\\lnot\forall x~\phi\iff\exists x~\lnot\phi\\\text{et cetera}}$